# Bootstrap - default width extended slightly to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having this strange behavior of Twitter Bootstrap. I have a full-width layout which I divide a row into an 8:4 grid ratio.

Now, it happens to me that there is a little bit of the width being extended to the right, causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear. The extending bit is just around 20px, but I can't seem to find where it comes from.

I tried to set any possible padding to 0px to my html and body tag, but there's no luck.

Screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Some code, though I'm pretty sure you will not find anything interesting, quite a basic code.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div id="left-pan" class="col-md-8">
    <div id="control">
        Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-pan" class="col-md-4">
    Lorem
  </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    background-color: darken(@slate, 10%);
    font-family: 'Carme', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
}

#left-pan {}
#right-pan {}
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Edited, have a check.

Comment: If you provide a working example. It's more batter to understand/track your problem.

Comment: Actually u need to put the code may be in a fiddle or your website link . what bootstrap does is not easily guessable seeing the code .

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong but using the Twitter bootstrap requires you wrap all "rows" in a container... see this link here

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

I created a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JgPaa/4/ with your code ..note if u remove the container you get the effect you mention...the scroll bars ..with the container ...no scroll bars.  Now the container will not go full width because its padded..you can tweak that yourself via custom css.
from the bootstrap css

```
container{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}
```

Does that cover it?